# Indenting borders for table row <tr>

Tags: css

I have parent child relationship table

http://jsfiddle.net/ZPSVg/

html

```
<table>

<tr class="parent_row">
    <td >1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td><a>Link</a></td>
    <td style="width:20px;"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="child_row">
    <td >1.1</td>
    <td>2.1</td>
    <td>3.1</td>
    <td><a>Link_child</a></td>
</tr>
<tr class="parent_row">
    <td >1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td><a>Link</a></td>
    <td style="width:20px;"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="child_row">
    <td >1.2</td>
    <td>2.2</td>
    <td>3.2</td>
    <td><a>Link_child</a></td>
    <td style="width:20px;"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

css

```
table{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

tr{
    border-color: #D8D8D8;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px 0 0;
    line-height:2em;
    font-size:14px;
}

td:first-child{
    padding-left:20px;
}

.child_row{
    border-style:dotted;
}
```

Now both parent row and child row have borders. Parent rows have solid while child rows have dotted.

For child rows the dotted border should start where text starts rather at the left end.

w.r.t to the code for child rows it should start at 1.1 and 2.1

I tried to cut the border image and place it as background for tr positioning 20px from left but i am not able to get it work since i hav given repeat-x( for handling all screen size).

Is there any other work around for this? the text in parent and child rows should be inline

**UPDATED the jsfiddle**

the solution should support cross browser compatibilty from ie8, chrome , safari, firefox.

Comment: Pretty Unclear ... consider add your code and a http://jsfiddle.net / or screenshots

Comment: post relevant HTML,CSS code.

Comment: If you used `tr + tr {text-indent: 20px;}` would this work? It's really hard to understand what you are asking with this question. I added this here as a starting point but seeing the code would be quite helpful.

Answer (score 6):

> since tr doesn't accept margin or padding i am unable to do an indenation like that.

Have you tried using `td` with the `first-child` selector? Like so:

```
tr.child_row td:first-child { padding-left:20px; }
```

Or if you would like to indent every cell of the child row (which kinda makes sense looking at your example), remove :first-child:

```
tr.child_row td { padding-left:20px; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZPSVg/23/ updated jsFiddle to show the latter.

Comment: This seems the proper way to indent table rows.  Adding extraneous columns for padding seems to invite accessibility concerns.

Answer (score 2):

You are going to need to use an empty td with a set width in the child element and colspan that on the parent.

```
<tr>
     <td colspan="2">Parent</td>
</tr>
<tr>
     <td style="width: 20px;"></td><td>Child</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use  **text-indent**

```
<tr>
     <td colspan="2">Parent</td>
</tr>
<tr>
     <td style="text-indent: 1em;"></td><td>Child</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score -2):

This is how to produce a real right or left margin on an table row. This should work on a contemporary browser as well as on a prehistoric one.

**1/ Table WITHOUT borders or background color:**

[image: Left margin on TR tag]

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>AA</td>
        <td>BBBBBBBBB</td>
        <td>CCCC</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="leftMargin">
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```css
.leftMargin td {  
    position: relative;  
    left: 60px;  
    z-index: 1;  
}
```

**2/ Table WITH cell borders and background color:**

[image: Left margin on TR tag - cells borders and background color]

```html
<table>  
    <tr>  
        <td>AA</td>  
        <td>BBBBBBBBB</td>  
        <td>CCCC</td>  
    </tr>  
    <tr class="leftMargin">  
        <td><div class="column1">A</div></td>  
        <td><div>B</div></td>  
        <td><div>C</div></td>  
    </tr>  
    <tr>  
        <td>A</td>  
        <td>B</td>  
        <td>C</td>  
    </tr>  
</table>
```

```css
table{  
    border-collapse: collapse;  
}  

td {  
    border: solid 1px red;  
    background-color:yellow;  
}  

.leftMargin td {  
    border: none;  
    background-color: transparent;  
    padding: 0 0;  
}  

.leftMargin div {  
    position: relative;  
    left: 60px;  
    z-index: 1;  
    border-top: solid 1px red;  
    border-right: solid 1px red;  
    border-bottom: solid 1px red;  
    background-color: yellow;  
    margin: -1px 0;  
}  

.leftMargin div.column1 {  
    border-left: solid 1px red;  
}
```

**Browser support:**

This HTML/CSS code was successfully tested on:

Desktop browsers:

- Windows:
  IE 9
  IE 11 + IE 5,7,8,9,10 emulation
  Edge 42
  Chrome 5, 70
  Firefox 3.6, 64
  Safari 4.0.3
- By means of https://netrenderer.com/index.php:
  IE 5.5
- By means of https://www.browserling.com/:
  Opera 10

Mobile browsers:

- Android 4.1.2 (Jelly Bean):
  Safari 4.0
  Chrome 26
  Firefox 58
- iPhone 6.1.6 (iPhone 3GS with most recent OS update):
  Safari 6.0
  Chrome 29
- iPad Air OS 12.1.1:
  Safari 12